# visualise instance of concepts in protègè 4.3

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, ontology, protege, protege4

Good Day, 
I want to visualise the concepts and their instances in protege 4.3. unfortunately I don't find the OntoViz plugin in this version. 
Can you help in this context are there other plugin for this task for example 
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

OntoViz is an old plugin and might not work in Protege 4.3.

Take a look at:

- [Protege visualization plugins](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Visualization) page
- list of [plugins compatible with Protege 4.3](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege-OWL_4.3) (take a look at VOWL)

There is also [OWLGrEd - graphical OWL editor](http://owlgred.lumii.lv/) for Windows in which you can build ontologies by drawing / editing their visual representation (disclaimer: I know people who develop it).

- see also: OWLGrEd [online ontology visualizer](http://owlgred.lumii.lv/online_visualization)

Comment: Thanks a lot I will check this link